# Lua: Functions with Tables for Beginners - Proper Naming/Retrieving of Tables within Tables

Tags: function, lua, lua-table

I am having a horrible time at grasping functions and tables.  I've asked a question before that is similar to this but still am having problems getting this to work properly.  So I will be more descriptive.  But just when I think I understand it I completely confuse myself again.  Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a program that is receiving its `input` from an outside source.  It needs to take that `input`, and basically "dissect" the strings to get the required information.  Based on the information it receives, it moves onto the next phase or functions to do the appropriate actions.  For example:

input is received as `NY345,de,M,9900`

I created a table that has all of the different ways the specific input can begin, such as:

```
local t = {["NY"] = 5, ["MS"] = 7, ["HG"] = 10, ["JX"] = 14, ["UY"] = 20}
```

Now I want to use a function to receive the input and look for `k` in `t{}` and use that to gather other variables...

```
function seek(input)
    for k, v in pairs (seek) do
        local info = string.match(input,k)
            if info then
                return {seekData = string.match(input,k..",(%d*),.*"), seekMult = seekData*v}
            end
    end
end
```

How far off am I?

If I had the table "`t = {...}`" above, and that contained other tables; how can I name each table inside of "`t = {...}`" and retrieve it for other equations?  Such as if ["a"] = 8, the rest of that table was to be utilized?  For example:

`t={["a"] = 2, ["b"] = 3, ["c"] = "IOS"},{["a"] = 8, ["b"] = 9, ["c"] = "NVY"},{["a"] = 1, ["b"] = 5, ["c"] = "CWQ"}}`

```
if a = 8, then b = 9 and c = "NVY"
```

I would like my function to search k (of each table) and compare it with the input.  If that was found, then it would  set the other two local variables to `b` and `c`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In your first snippet I think you meant `pairs(t)` instead of `pairs(seek)`. lua's print function does not pretty-print a table for you. You need to walk the fields yourself or get a table pretty-printer. So `print(Brian)` is just going to print the table identifier. Also your `person` function wants to iterate (with `pairs`) over the `name` table argument instead of over the constant `t` table.

Comment: Please ask about one issue at a time. You'll be more likely to get answers for each of them and the questions will be clearer for future readers.

Comment: Questions 2 and 3 should be separate, they are unclear as is and sufficiently distinct from first. You'll have to clarify and give examples.

Comment: Ok.  I apologize and will create another thread topic more suitable for QUESTIONS 2 & 3.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @EtanReisner You are correct.  That was a typo and I did mean `pairs(t)`.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @EtanReisner I've updated my post to remove the other two questions.  Thanks for your input, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will only answer question 1, as 2 and 3 should be separate questions. There are many ways to do this based on specifics you don't mention but assuming you have a table t like this:

```
t={
    {["a"] = 2, ["b"] = 3, ["c"] = "IOS"},
    {["a"] = 8, ["b"] = 9, ["c"] = "NVY"},
    {["a"] = 1, ["b"] = 5, ["c"] = "CWQ"}
}
```

then a function that takes an `a` key value to look for and returns b and c:

```
function findItem(a, yourTable)
    for i,tt in ipairs(yourTable) do
         if tt.a == a then
              return i, tt.b, tt.c
         end
    end
end
```

With this, if the input is k, then

```
i, b, c = findItem(k, t)
if i == nil then
     print('could not find k')
else
     print('found k at index ' .. i) 
end
```

The `findItem` could of course just return the subtable found, and maybe you don't need index:

```
function findItem(a, yourTable)
    for i,tt in ipairs(yourTable) do
         if tt.a == a then
              return tt
         end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I do have a question concerning your answer.  `for i, tt in yourTable do`, can you please explain what is going on with that statement and what `tt` is meant with it?  I'm guessing you are iterating "For each table inside of table(t)"?  Thanks!

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 it should have been `ipairs(yourTable)`. Yes this iterates over each array item in `yourTable`, starting at i=1 until Lua hits first nil entry. You can read more about `ipairs()` in Lua online ref manual and Programming in Lua (PIL) (1st ed free online, 2nd or 3rd can be purchased).

Comment: thanks for your help.  I bought both books and read both extensively.  But I still have issues understanding how to iterate over tables nested into other tables and functions.  Also, trying to understand how to retrieve information within tables.  But your answer does help me a bit.  I have no programming background so I'm doing my best.  Thank you!